# Searching for an item linked list C (queue)

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, traversal

I have two structs name *head and *tail.

I use head for start of linked list and tail for the end.

Lets say I have a linked list with an arbitrary amount of elements

```
typedef struct queue
{
    int stuff;
    struct queue *nextNode;
}q;
```

In one of my nodes, stuff = 164 (this is hypothetical)

How would I go about searching through my linked list to find 164?

Thank you!

Comment: Iterate: inspect the first one. If it is 164 you are done. Else inspect the next node (unless NULL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab a pointer to the head of the linked list. Assuming that the last item in the list is marked with its `nextNode` pointer being `NULL`, you can iterate through the list one by one:

```
struct queue *tmp = head;
while (tmp != NULL) {
    if (tmp->stuff == 164) {
        // found it!
        break;
    }
    tmp = tmp->nextNode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate across your queue

```
struct queue *current = head;

while(current != NULL)
{
    if(current->stuff == numToSearch)
        // found it
    current = current->nextNode;

}
```

note: pardon any minor syntax errors, it's been a while since i've touched c

Answer (score 0):

```
struct queue *find(struct queue *ptr, int val) {
 for ( ; ptr; ptr = ptr->nextNode) {
     if (ptr->stuff == val) break;
     }
 return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with head. While not reached tail and current item value is not the one we're looking for go to next node. If item finished the loop is not the one we're looking for -> such an item doesn't exist in the list. Code is written in the assumption that tail pointer is not NULL.

```
struct queue* item = head;
while (item != tail && item->stuff != 164) {
    item = item->nextNode;
}
if (164 == item->stuff) {
// do the found thing
} else {
// do the not found thing
}
```